# Returning the custom return type upon exception in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read xml using the following method to extract data from xml

```
def xmlparser(xml:String): (String,List[String]) =
 Try {
    val documentbuilder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance.newDocumentBuilder
    val xmldocument = documentbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(xml)))
    val nodesofchild=xmldocument.getChildNodes
    val xmlvalues=extractvalues(nodesofchild)
   ("xmlname",xmlvalues)
  }
```

I need to return ("xmlname",xmlvalues) if xml is valid ,else i need to return ("xmlname",null).I tried using ".toOption.orNull" but it is returning only "null".Could somebody help me how to return ("xmlname",null) instead of "null"

Comment: `.toOption.getOrElse("xmlname" -> null)`. But ... don't use nulls. Nulls are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your current code:

```
def xmlparser(xml:String): (String, Option[List[String]]) =
 val values = Try {
   val documentbuilder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance.newDocumentBuilder
   val xmldocument = documentbuilder.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(xml)))
   val nodesofchild=xmldocument.getChildNodes
   val xmlvalues=extractvalues(nodesofchild)
  }
  ("xmlname", xmlvalues.toOption)
 }
```

Comment: xmlvalues is not taking .toOption conversion